# Customise product to have addons that appear as one item in cart

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

How do I create [image: add something like this?]

I can create all the html & css but not sure how to connect the liquid logic behind it.

I've tried with apps and it currently behaved like:

user adds 4 qty(4 metres of rope) and then selects how the end of the rope is treated (ie Heat shrink for $5).
It adds the 4xQTY of rope to the cart with 4xqty of the $5 - Heat shrink.

Expected behaviour:

user adds 4 qty(4 metres of rope) with the dropdown addon of Heat shrink for $5.

It adds to the cart 4xqty Product and $5 once because the whole item is a single item.